# Reusing client in a WCF service in .Net 3.5

Tags: wcf

I understand that ClientBase<> has inbuilt caching added to it for the channel factories. But it should be in later versions of .Net (4.5) : [more here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh314046(v=vs.110).aspx)

Now, am having a simple sample project to see if the same client is reused or a new is created for every call to analyse the time taken. Below is some code snippet:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ISoapService
{
    [OperationContract]
    string GetData(int value);
}
```

Client Code:

```
private static void NonCachedVersion()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Non-Cached Version");
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        using (var client = new SoapServiceReference.SoapServiceClient())
        {
            client.GetData(5);
            watch.Stop();
        }
        Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}ms", i, watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    }
}

private static void CachedVersion()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Cached Version");
    using (var client = new SoapServiceReference.SoapServiceClient())
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            client.GetData(5);
            watch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}ms", i, watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        }
        client.Close();
    }
}
```

Calling them:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    NonCachedVersion();
    Console.WriteLine();
    CachedVersion();
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

And here's the output:

```
Non-Cached Version
0: 2030ms
1: 22ms
2: 19ms
3: 21ms
4: 18ms

Cached Version
0: 19ms
1: 7ms
2: 7ms
3: 7ms
4: 8ms
```

Also, if I call the cached version first and then the non-cached version, timings are follows:

```
Cached Version
0: 2275ms
1: 13ms
2: 8ms
3: 8ms
4: 8ms

Non-Cached Version
0: 19ms
1: 18ms
2: 18ms
3: 18ms
4: 19ms
```

Thus, it is essentially the first call that is expensive, rest seem to be utilizing some sort of cache.

So, few things:

1. For Non-cached version - even though the client is disposed after every call, next client create is very fast compared to the first call. Caching of the channel happening despite dispose?
2. For Cached version - time is less than non-cached version as its taking that extra time to create the client object. Correct?
3. Product is compiled for .Net 3.5, is caching enabled in that for the channels? I see that the [CacheSetting property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh160401(v=vs.110).aspx) is added in .Net 4.5 only.